# Configure SCIM user provisioning with GSuite Google Workspace

Tags: saml, google-apps, google-workspace, scim, scim2

I would like to provision my SaaS application and Google Workspace (ex GSuite) using SCIM. I do not find any documentation for this. Just a list of pre-configured applications.

It seems to be well supported on [Microsoft Azure AD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/app-provisioning/use-scim-to-provision-users-and-groups) and other identity providers like Okta or OneLogin.

PS: I am not interested in SAML configuration (for authentication). Only by user provisioning.

Comment: Apparently not possible for normal users: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72691185/doc-about-scim-implementation-for-google-workspace. Maybe via an account rep, but guessing the app has to be large to include in their catalog.

Answer (score 1):

Last time I checked any app inclusion request to their SAML App Catalog or auto provisioning catalog has to go through some review. You can submit the request by filling out this [form](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSdQZYsNg2uu_PZYFeSKudkT6fV1PoMPylTfnHK6PWVYrdMtNQ/viewform)

Be aware responses may take weeks due to the demand and process they have to go through.