# Doc about SCIM implementation for Google Workspace?

Tags: google-workspace, scim

I need to develop a SCIM endpoint for Azure and Google Workspace.

Azure and Okta have a good technical documentation about it, but I can't find anything on the Google side. All I can find is some help about how to configure an app from the catalog.

I need to know if Google is full SCIM standard or if they have some quirks like Azure does.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

What's tricky with Google is the fact that they do not support custom SCIM implementations, they do allow any custom SAML integration but when it comes to SCIM you can only use the ones available in the [catalog](https://support.google.com/a/topic/10018788)

That's why there's not much info about it out there.

#### References:

[Google's automatic provisioning](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7681608?hl=en&ref_topic=6400789)