# How can I add User provisioning to my App

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

I would like to know how I integrate Google SCIM with my SCIM API so that our customers can provision users using this feature?

Comment: Could you be more specific? What exactly would you like to integrate? What Google product would be involved in that? What would be the desired end result? Thanks!

Comment: Hi, it would be integrating my application with the Google SCIM API to allow automated user provisioning from users in customers Google tenants into my application, I have posted an example of  an app that offers this. https://asana.com/apps/google-security

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Doc about SCIM implementation for Google Workspace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72691185/doc-about-scim-implementation-for-google-workspace)